# Windows domain runas without password

Tags: windows, permissions, domain

There are several articles out there where "runas" can be executed without prompting for password in a script. However my situation is slightly unique -

I have two accounts in my Windows Domain Controller - a user account in my domain controller and second managed account (which I have no control of what password is at any instant of time). The user account must be able to invoke a process as the managed account - the idea is that the managed account kerberos credentials are then used to connect to other services in the network.

Which privileges in domain controller on the managed account give the user such privileges? The issue here is not about password prompt but execute runas /netonly without password at all.

Can anyone please help

Comment: You might be looking for `runas /netonly /savecred`, but this combination of both switches is not allowed. I think you would need to either specify the password somewhere, but is that unacceptable?

Comment: Would [S4U](https://serverfault.com/questions/334839/how-to-create-a-password-less-service-account-in-ad) work in this case? The issue is that I have no control on the service account password - however I can control any privilege on service account user object.